# How to list an array with the coordinates of the pixels that are inside a circle

Tags: python-2.7

I'm targeting an image and a part to be selected is within a circle, I need the coordinates (x, y) of all pixels within the circle.

I'm using python, a library: from matplotlib.patches import Circle

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

raioelet = 20
raio = Circle((50, 65, raioelet, fill=False, linestyle='dashed')
ax.add_artist(raio)
```

The above code has a circle delineation of an area of 20 from the coordinates X = 50 and Y = 65

Question:

How do I list in an array just as coordinates that lie within the bounds of the circle?

Comment: by "in the circle" do you mean: 1. pixels which are entirely in the circle, 2. pixels which are 50% or more in the circle, or 3. pixels which touch the circle?

Comment: **that's right**